# Filtering out rows of data based on criteria from different columns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have data from an experiment in which each row is a different trial. The table has several columns with information about the trial, and then 1000 columns of data.

I need to filter out certain trials (rows) based on various criteria in order to calculate means from valid trials only. For example, I have a column with accuracy data (0 = error, 1 = correct), and a column with response time data (need to filter out responses < 200). I assume I need to loop through each row to create a new true/false logical column based on my criteria (e.g., valid trials are accuracy == 1 & RT > 200).

Then, I need to create means of only valid trials grouped by conditions which are defined by strings in another column (e.g., create 3 means based on a valence column with "negative", "neutral" and "positive"). I know this is probably relatively simple to do, I am new to MATLAB. All suggestions appreciated.

```
Valence  Acc RTs NumNan Data1 
'Negative' 1 540 0 278.5148611 
'Negative' 1 597 0 89.18152778 
'Negative' 1 381 0 173.5148611 
'Negative' 1 471 0 19.51486111 
'Negative' 1 535 0 2.514861111
```

Comment: Could you show a few example rows of actual matrix?

Comment: Sure. e.g:
Valence Acc RTs NumNan Data1
'Negative' 1 540 0 278.5148611
'Negative' 1 597 0 89.18152778
'Negative' 1 381 0 173.5148611
'Negative' 1 471 0 19.51486111
'Negative' 1 535 0 2.514861111

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Not sure how to best display it.
Headers are 
Valence, Acc, RTs, NumNan, Data1
Data are e.g.: 
'Negative', 1, 381, 0, 173.51

Comment: Consider creating a [table](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) and then access the table by adding conditions on each column, as shown in [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can operate with boolean logic.

Suppose your data is stored in matrix `A`.

```
cond1 = A(:,2) == 1; % only select 'accurate' data 
cond2 = A(:,3) < 200; % response time <200 
cond3 = A(:,1) ~= 'Negative'; % non-negative trials

idx = cond1 & cond2 & cond3; % use 'AND' logic to find indices of satisfying records
B = A(idx,:); % pick out selected records and save in new matrix
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have specified that my data is a table, so I get this error: 
"Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'table'."
 I tried using table2array but that doesn't work because of my strings.

Comment: Never mind, needs {} instead of ()
Thank you very much!